# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.4, typeerror

I'm getting this error when reading from a file:

```
line 70 in main: score += points
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

I'm taking an integer in the file and adding it to the variable `score`. The reading from the file is done in the `next_line` function which is then called in the `next_block` function.

I have tried converting both `score` and `points` to an integer which doesn't seem to work.

Here's the program code:

```
# Trivia Challenge
# Trivia game that reads a plain text file

import sys

def open_file(file_name, mode):
    """Open a file."""
    try:
        the_file = open(file_name, mode)
    except IOError as e:
        print("Unable to open the file", file_name, "Ending program.\n",e)
        input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    """Return next line from the trivia file, formatted."""
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line

def next_block(the_file):
    """Return the next block of data from the trivia file."""
    category = next_line(the_file)

    question = next_line(the_file)

    answers = []
    for i in range(4):
        answers.append(next_line(the_file))

    correct = next_line(the_file)
    if correct:
        correct = correct[0]

    explanation = next_line(the_file)

    points = next_line(the_file)

    return category, question, answers, correct, explanation, points

def welcome(title):
    """Welcome the player and get his/her name."""
    print("\t\tWelcome to Trivia Challenge!\n")
    print("\t\t", title, "\n")

def main():
    trivia_file = open_file("trivia.txt", "r")
    title = next_line(trivia_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0

    # get first block
    category, question, answers, correct, explanation, points = next_block(trivia_file)
    while category:
        # ask a question
        print(category)
        print(question)
        for i in range(4):
            print("\t", i + 1, "-", answers[i])

        # get answer
        answer = input("What's your answer?: ")

        # check answer
        if answer == correct:
            print("\nRight!", end= " ")
            score += points
        else:
            print("\nWrong.", end= " ")
        print(explanation)
        print("Score:", score, "\n\n")

        # get next block
        category, question, answers, correct, explanation, points = next_block(trivia_file)

    trivia_file.close()

    print("That was the last question!")
    print("Your final score is", score)

main()
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`points` is a string, because you read this from the file:

```
points = next_line(the_file)
```

but `score` is an integer:

```
score = 0
```

You can't add a string to an integer. If the value you read from the file represents an integer number, you need to convert it first, using `int()`:

```
score += int(points)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I was trying to convert the function call to an integer which is why it wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

When receiving an error message, it can often reveal useful information about a problem...
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'` is basically saying that one can't use the `+=` operator (which can be simplified to `+`) with the two different types of objects it received (string and integer, in your case).
Your `points` object is of type integer, whilst your `score` is a string (since it was read from a file).
To correct this, you must convert the string to an integer, allowing you to sum it with the other integer, this can be done using the `int()` function.
tl;dr: `type(1)`!=`type('1')`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to add `int` and `str`

```
score = int(score)
score += points
```